# Spring framework HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, post, axios

I'm trying to make a post request in React to a backend server in `Spring`, but keep getting the error bellow:

> [ERROR] -
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing.

It works fine on postman.

Code from the react part:

```
let testeDTO = JSON.stringify({
  email: "teste@@teste.com",
  senha: "1234",
  grupo: 1
});

axios
  .post("http://192.168.0.49:8080/site/login/", testeDTO, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(erro => {
    console.log(erro.response);
  });
```

Annotations on the rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/site/login")
```

Code from Spring:

```
@PostMapping
public testeDTO login(@RequestBody TesteDTO testeDTO) {

}
```

CORS class:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*, Content-Type, authorization, grupo, usuario");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

DTO code:

```
public class TesteDTO {

    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private Long grupo;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: try `@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the error persisted after i change my annotation on the method to: @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json"). Edited the question to add my CORS class.

Comment: Please share the code of `TesteDTO`. Are you able to see the request received by Spring (by e.g. setting a breakpoint in your filter)?

Comment: Also, from what I see, it should be possible to pass the payload as JavaScript-/TypeScript-Object to `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`, so the manual marshalling seems unnecessar.y

Comment: Teste dto only has the atributtes email, senha and grupo. No its doesnt reach any breakpoints on the backend, the error happens before the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the header on the axios post needed to be wrapped in {}. So, after way too long this solved for me, leaving it here for those who stumble in this question with a similar problem.

```
var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
    };
axios
  .post("http://192.168.0.49:8080/site/login/", testeDTO, {headers})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(erro => {
    console.log(erro.response);
  });
```